# whether the connection made my power bi service to import data from excel-source file is live

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I got a doubt, which would be very a simple one and concerns me to build confidence in demonstrating my knowledge.

I imported data from excel-source (in local machine) to Power BI Service directly; well, my concern is whether the connection  made by Power BI service to excel-source-file will be considered as a live connection.

Thank you for giving time to address my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not work as live connection. So whatever changes you made in local excel file will not appear at service until or unless you will upload a updated file to service.